# What data type to be used for storing dates like '01-05'?

Tags: mysql, date

I want to store the list of all public holidays in a year.
Then the employees can avail the leaves for these days. The leave details will be stored in another table.

My issue is that I need to have a table for listing all the public holidays and the corresponding leaves.

Ex- 1st May must be listed for May Day.

However, I can't give date here (01-05-2014) because the same dates (01-05) will occur in each year.

So, how can I store these dates in a mysql table.

My current table structure is:

```
mysql> desc table;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| leaveCode | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, I use date as the data type for the date.
But, It's not working.

When I tried inserting the values, the dates field is not getting populated.

```
<pre>
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', 'May Day', 'MD', '01-05');
</pre>
```

I need a method to store these dates in the format - DD-MM in the table (Ex: 01-05).

Can someone please help me.

Comment: how can 01-05-2014 occur each year?

Comment: btw mysql date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Bojan, I meant that 01-05 will occur in each year.

Comment: aha,i did not get that. Anyway,that is not date column then. So as Leo said you can use separate day and month values, or use "date" as varchar value and then process it when needed. Leos suggestion is better, as if you have large data set, processing would be slow in second case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather prefer to store the day and the month in separate numeric fields, just because if you store a date, you must have to choose an arbitrary year with 366 days...

The concept of Date is a moment in time. You're not storing a date, although you could use the Date representation to store your infomation.

BUT, if you really want to use the Date column, you can choose some arbitrary leap year and set your "date" as YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a holiday list as just month and day, because holidays vary from year-to-year on the calendars most commonly used for business.  Religious holidays are notorious for wandering around the calendar.  Consider:

- Easter
- Passover
- Ramadan

Add to that holidays such as the Chinese New Year, American Thanksgiving, and American President's Day and you might start to think that calendar days have nothing to do with holidays.  Okay, there are a few -- New Year's Day, May Day, Fourth of July, and Bastille Day.  In the United States, there is a tendency to move national holidays onto a Monday, when the holiday would occur on the weekend.

You need a holiday table or calendar table with holiday information.  When I've needed such a beast in the past, I've just used the holidays list provided with gmacs.  I'm pretty sure there are other sources on the web for this information.

Comment: We only need the fixed days like May Day